# Problems with parsing facebook using Jsoup

Tags: java, facebook, jsoup

I wrote a program to parse facebook, and I can get the whole DOM tree already. Things go well but when I want to select all `<p>`-tags, the problem is it returns a zero sized array.
PS: Nothing goes wrong when I parse other websites but facebook.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    doc = connect(); //connect the website,
    System.out.print(doc.outerHtml());//in the wole html file, i can find the tag <p>
    newsHeadlines = doc.select("p"); //nothing
    doc.getElementsByTag("p");//nothing either
    oldEleStr = newsHeadlines.text();
    System.out.println(oldEleStr);//nothing
}


static Document connect() throws IOException {
    org.jsoup.Connection connection = Jsoup
            .connect("facebook.com")
            .cookies(
                    splitCookies(facebookCookies));
    Document doc = connection.get();
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste here the html code that Jsoup fail to parse?

Comment: What version of JSoup do you use? It yells "no protocol specified" when there's just "facebook.com" (not "http://facebook.com"). After changing protocol it works as expected

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've solved the problem. It is because all the tags <p> in a annotation scope(when I parse it), aha, I don't know why.The question is that when I view the facebook's source code in my browser, the tags <p> are not in the annotation scope.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like:

```
Document new_doc = Jsoup.parse(doc.outerHtml());
Elements elements = doc.select("p");
for (Element aa : elements) {
    //TODO:
}
```